# SHELL: MySQL commands returns NULL

Tags: bash

I need some I have this code

```
ignore_tbl=("mg_de_reifen_import_temp" "mg_de_reifen_import" "mg_de_reifen_import_last")

until mysqladmin -u$dbUser -p$dbPass ping; do echo "Waiting for mysqld"; sleep 10; done
mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "create database if not exists $dbName"

    IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
                            for TABLE in "${ignore_tbl[@]}"
                                do
                                   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+="table_schema = 'exclude_test' AND table_name LIKE '${TABLE}' AND "
                                done
                                TEST="${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING:0:-5}"

                            echo $TEST

mg_=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 200000; SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE $TEST;" -s` echo $mg_
```

it returns NULL

the result is

```
mysqld is alive
    table_schema = 'exclude_test' AND table_name LIKE    'mg_de_reifen_import_temp' AND table_schema = 'exclude_test' AND table_name LIKE 'mg_de_reifen_import' AND table_schema = 'exclude_test' AND table_name LIKE 'mg_de_reifen_import_last'
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test can never succeed as `'mg_de_reifen_import_temp` is not like `mg_de_reifen_import_last` - you need to adjust how you're building up that test statement, perhaps you want something more like:

```
table_schema = 'exclude_test' AND table_name IN ( 'mg_de_reifen_import_temp', 'mg_de_reifen_import', 'mg_de_reifen_import_last' )
```